# Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am getting this error within my plug-in.

```
Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/stageidg/public_html/10milemovers/wp-content/plugins/chauffeur-booking-system/class/CHBS.PaymentStripe.class.php on line 191
```

Here is line 191

```
        if(!((array_key_exists('payment_data',$this->data['meta'])) && (is_array($meta['payment_data']))))

            $meta['payment_data']=array();

        array_push($meta['payment_data'],$paymentData);CHBSPostMeta::updatePostMeta($bookingId,'payment_data',$meta['payment_data']);

        return(true);
```

any idea what is causing the error?

Comment: Yea, `$this->data['meta']` is not an array. Simples! Possibly it does not even exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array $this->data['meta'] is null and not even initialized to an empty array.

When you first call array_key_exists

Comment: This is just a comment. You have enough reps to make comments so please feel free to do so

Comment: how would i fix that? any adjustment i make to this plug-in breaks or doesn't pass the payment

Comment: i literally just had to hide all the errors since it doesnt stop the plug-in from working

Comment: Sorry I was travelling at the time. Is this code within the plugin, or with in your code? You could add an additional check before array_key_exists checking to see if $this->data['meta'] is a defined array and only call array_key_exists if it is. You could also try searching the rest of the code for references to data['meta'] and see where/when it gets initialized if at all... if its part of the plugin its probably something that gets passed in during initialization and that is not correctly defined and time of initialization.